# How to concatenate like List comprehension

Tags: pytorch, concatenation

I want to do without define input_list and output_list befor for like "List comprehension"
Please tell me how to do in this case?

Thank you.

```
e.g.
inputs = torch.rand(1,5)
weights = torch.rand(5,5)

def training(self,inputs,weights,steps=50):
    input_list=torch.empty(1,5)
    output_list=torch.empty(5,5)

    for i in range(steps):
        outputs = torch.matmul(inputs,weights)

        input_list = torch.cat([input_list,inputs], axis=0)
        output_list = torch.cat([output_list,outputs], axis=0)

        inputs = outputs

    return inputs,input_list,output_list
```

them
input_list is
tensor([[1.8367e-36, 0.0000e+00, 3.3631e-44, 0.0000e+00,        nan],
[3.9109e-01, 8.9431e-01, 6.8890e-01, 8.3894e-01, 1.7802e-01]])
I dont need the first Row. How to concatenate in this case?

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved by professional programer.

like this;

```
input_list=torch.tensor([])
output_list=torch.tensor([])
```

Reference;
https://teratail.com/questions/298576